# Limit of $(x_1^2+2x_1x_2)/\|x\|$ as $\|x\| \to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, normed-spaces

I am having a difficult time proving the following:

$\lim_{\|x\|\to 0} \frac{x_1^2+2x_1x_2}{\|x\|} = 0$, where $x = (x_1,x_2)$.

I've tried expanding the numerator as $(x_1+x_2)^2 - x_2^2$ and the denominator as $\sqrt{(x_1+x_2)^2-2x_1x_2}$ but I don't know how to further reduce the expression.

Another approach I tried was expanding the numerator as $\|x\|+2x_1x_2-x_2^2$ which I also have problem reducing it further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all $x\ne 0$ we have
$$
\left|\dfrac{x_1^2+2x_1x_2}{\|x\|}\right|=\dfrac{\left|x_1^2+2x_1x_2\right|}{\|x\|}\le \dfrac{x_1^2+2|x_1||x_2|}{\|x\|}\le \dfrac{\|x\|^2+2\|x\|^2}{\|x\|}=3\|x\|.
$$
Therefore
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{x_1^2+2x_1x_2}{\|x\|}=0.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
\frac{x_1^2+2x_1x_2}{(x_1^2+x_2^2)^{1/2}}=
\frac{x_1}{(x_1^2+x_2^2)^{1/2}}(x_1+2x_2)
$$
and that
$$
\biggl|\frac{x_1}{(x_1^2+x_2^2)^{1/2}}\biggr|\le 1
$$
Thus
$$
\biggl|\frac{x_1^2+2x_1x_2}{(x_1^2+x_2^2)^{1/2}}\biggr|\le|x_1+2x_2|
$$

Comment: That's quite elegant. +1

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $(x,y)$ lies on the circle with radius $r$ and center $0$. Then there exists $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$ such that $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$. Hence
$$
\frac{x^2+2xy}{r}=r (\sin^2\theta+2\sin\theta\cos\theta)= r(\sin^2\theta+\sin(2\theta)) \le 2r.
$$

Comment: @egreg thanks for the edit, for some reason I didn't see the 2 at a certain point :)